# Difference between deployment and hosting

Tags: deployment, hosting

What is the difference between hosting and deployment? Do web apps, android apps and websites get deployed or do they get hosted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deployment is phase of product lifecycle when software and data deployed , that is installed , delivered to environment, configured, etc. After that product enters in next phase - usage. And in this phase we can say that software and data is hosted. This steps can be repeated.

Answer (score 5):

The process of moving code from your local computer to a public host (server) is called **Deployment**. It is basically putting out your project to the world so that people can use it.

**Web hosting** is a service provided by Web Hosts. Web hosts are companies that provide this service which includes:

1. Web space for storing data of your website and
2. Domain name

For Example :
Netlify is a *web hosting company* and it is used for *deploying* static websites for free.